# laravel access child table content

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

User has projects (via pivot table).

Projects have surveys.

I can easily access users projects via pivot table (many to many model)

like so:

```
$user     = Auth::user();
$projects = $user->projects;
```

But in the same array I'd like to get surveys owned by the project owned by user.

Is this possible?

$user->projects->surveys?

I looked at hasmanythrough method provided by laravel but couldn't make it work. maybe its not meant for this..

Comment: You should be able to iterate `$projects->surveys`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this assuming your models are set up.

```
$surveys = User::with('project.survey') 
-> where('id',Auth::user()
-> get();
```

Comment: most welcome, you can read about it [Laravel eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)